# Log4j logging to file fails

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following configuration in `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=/data.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In my Java Product class I've provided the Logger and PropertyConfigurator in the startTask method

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Product.class);
public void startTask() {
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
try {
     service.create(product);
     logger.info("Creation started");
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Log Exception
     logger.error(e);
}

}
```

As a result there is a "Creation started" info message in the console. But nothing is logged into the `data.log` file. Could it be the problem with the file path? I have several modules in my project, each of them has a resources folder. And the `data.log` file is in the resources folder.

I tried to put the `data.log` file into the `D:\` root folder but it didn't help.

Comment: I think you are missing `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout`

Comment: @abel90 sorry, I did not include it into the config above. However I've got this line in my configuration.

Comment: try passing following `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to your command line, and you should have debug output from the logger itself; also change your path to `D:\\data.log`

Comment: Maybe your log4j.properties file is not in classpath? How are you running your application?

Comment: @abel90 I think you are right. I have several modules and want to configure logging in this one separately from other modules. The module I'm working in has a Spring `config.xml` with bean definitions. And it doesn't contain any information about `log4j.properties`. How should I configure it to be present in a classpath?